# discord.py ignore bots (client.command)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to role everyone in my server with a command I call `p!roleall <role>`, but it's not ignoring bots and I need help. No errors were provided. Thanks.

```py
@client.command()
async def roleall(ctx, role: discord.Role):
  for i in ctx.guild.members:
    if i == i.bot:
        ctx.send('e')
    try:
      await i.add_roles(role)
    except discord.errors.Forbidden:
      await ctx.send(f'`i do not have permissions to role {i.name}`')
      pass
```

Comment: maybe you shoud put code in `else:`

Comment: ok I will try it

Comment: Nope, its still adding the role to bots ;-;

Comment: I think its the problem with the `i = i.bot:`. because it isn't sending 'e'

Comment: then first use `print()` to see what you have in `i` and `i.bot`. Maybe you compare totally wrong values and maybe it should be `if i.bot is True:` or shorter `if i.bot:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Firstly, each ctx.send() requires an await. In regards to the i.bot, this returns a boolean, so no need to compare it.
The issue of it not ignoring bots stems from you not instructing the program to skip the rest of the code. A `continue` statement will do that for you.

```
@client.command()
async def roleall(ctx, role: discord.Role):
  for i in ctx.guild.members:
    if i.bot:
        await ctx.send('e')
        continue
    try:
      await i.add_roles(role)
    except discord.errors.Forbidden:
      await ctx.send(f'`i do not have permissions to role {i.name}`')
      pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try putting an

```
else:
```

before the try.

Also, change `ctx.send('e')` to `await ctx.send('e')`